# Applying models to data - Inheriting or accessing the attributes of a root class (data) from a sub-class (model)

Tags: class, inheritance, attributes, parent

I am fitting a number of models to several different datasets.  I would like to store the methods and attributes of the datasets (e.g. X, y, trainTestSplit(), etc.) in 'Dataset' objects, and store the the methods and attributes of the models (e.g. fit(), hyperparameters, scores, etc.) in 'Model' objects, and store the 'Models' in the 'Datasets' (several Models for each Dataset).

I have tried several different ways to make this work, including inheritance with the use of super(); indenting (nesting) the Model class inside the dataset class; and with functions in the Dataset class which can be called by the Model class.

This is about as close as I've come:

```
class Dataset :
    def __init__(self, X, y, attr) :
       self.X = X
       self.y = y
       self.attr = attr

    def trainTestSplit(self, **kwargs):
       self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(self.X, self.y, **kwargs)

class Model(Dataset) :
    def __init__(self, regressor):
        self.reg = regressor
        super().__init__(self)

    def fit(self):
        self.reg.fit(X=self.X_train, y=self.y_train)

    def predict(self):
        self.yPredict = self.reg.predict(X=self.X_test)
```

In the above, the variables are not accessible to the Model class, and so it returns and error.

If this worked, I would expect to be executing the following function calls, as examples.

Creating an instance of a Dataset object:

```
dataset_1 = Dataset(X, y, 'string')
```

Splitting data into training and test sets:

```
dataset_1.trainTestSplit(test_size=0.3))
```

Creating an instance of a Model, and applying it to a dataset:

```
dataset_1.svr = Model(SVR(hyperParams))
```

Fitting a model:

```
dataset_1.svr.fit()
```

Actually, if I'm thinking about this in the right way, the fit() method of the Model class could be applied as part of the **init**, so that it is fit to the dataset on instantiation.

Reading a training score:

```
dataset_1.svr.training_score_
```

Because I have so many datasets, and will be fitting numerous models to each, having the methods and attributes stored in this way seemed to make sense, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Is there any way to instantiate a class (call it a sub-class), such that it inherits or has access to the attributes or objects contained in another class (say a root class), and so the sub-class is contained as an object within the root class?  Or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I might have been trying to use classes where a dictionary would be better suited.

The following seems to accomplish what I'm trying to do, which is to store a dataset and the results of models applied to it in the one object (other attributes such as training/CV/test scores etc. are still to be added in the answer below).

If anyone has any suggestions/comments on how this can be done better please comment.

Thanks.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

class Dataset(object):

def __init__(self, X, y):
    self.X = X
    self.y = y
    self.models = {}

def add_model(self, model, regressor):
    self.models[model] = {}
    self.models[model]['reg'] = regressor
    regressor.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)
    yPredict = regressor.predict(self.X_test)
    self.models[model]['yPredict'] = yPredict

def trainTestSplit(self, **kwargs):
   self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(self.X, self.y, **kwargs)
```